# Load jQuery function from a href onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, modal-dialog, partial-views

I have a HTML table with a column per row with this html code inside the `<td></td>` tags:

```
 <a onclick="modalDialog(this); return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">17795</a>
    <div style="display: none;" class="MessageDataDiv">
     some text to show up in my jquery modal window when function modaldialog is clicked.
    </div>
```

And the jQuery function that is called when `onclick` is fired within a `href` link

```
function modalDialog(event) {
        $('a.message').click(function () {
         var div = new $(this).closest("td").find(".MessageDataDiv").clone();
         div.show().dialog();
          event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```

How can I write the jQuery function so the function only fires one time when the linked is clicked? I need to have the jQuery function modalDialog as a separate function because the html table use AJAX partial rendering.

The problem is when I click the a href link first time nothing happens, second click on the links gives me two modal dialog and third click gives me three modal dialog and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to have a single div that shows every other text.

```
<div id="MessageDataDiv"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#MessageDataDiv').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
});
function modalDialog(a) {
  if($(a).data('clicked')) return false;
  $(a).data('clicked', true);
  $('#MessageDataDiv').html($(a).next().text()).dialog();
  return false;
}
</script>
```

This way you don't have to create a  every time you open a dialog.

Comment: this was a correct and cleaner way to rewrite my code with. It worked like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this;

On first entry:

```
  function modalDialog(event) {
    if (!$(document).data("clicked"))
    {
      $(document).data("clicked", true);
      $('a.message').click(function () {
        var div = new $(this).closest("td").find(".MessageDataDiv").clone();
        div.show().dialog();
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
```

You might also get away with using "return false;" instead of firing event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

I would do this differently. I would start with markup like this:

```
<div class="message">
  <a href="#">17795</a>
  <div>some text to show up in my jquery modal window when function modaldialog is clicked.</div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
div.message > div { display: none; }
```

and JS:

```
$("div.message > a").one("click", function() {
  $(this).next().dialog();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, you'd be better off using jQuery.one() rather than bind/unbind mess.

Docs:  http://api.jquery.com/one/